# Efficient way to select variables from a list of data frames by a list of list of character vectors

Tags: r, list, loops

I have a list of three data frames as follows

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- as.data.frame(replicate(n = 8, expr = round(rnorm(3), 2)))
colnames(dat) <- LETTERS[1:8]

dat_list <- list(dat1 = dat,
                 dat2 = dat[, 1:7],
                 dat3 = dat[, 1:4])
```

`dat3` is a subset of `dat2`, which is a subset of `dat1`.

I have another list of list, in which each object contains three named lists of character vectors. The character vectors refer to column names of the data sets from above. The list looks something like this

```
set.seed(1)
colnames_list <-
  lapply(c(6, 4, 2), function(x)
    replicate(n = 1, sample(
      names(dat), size = x, replace = FALSE
    )))
colnames_list <- lapply(colnames_list, as.vector)
names(colnames_list) <- names(dat_list)

model_list <- list(rpart = colnames_list,
                   lm = colnames_list)
model_list[1]
#$rpart
#$rpart$dat1
#[1] "C" "H" "D" "E" "A" "G"

#$rpart$dat2
#[1] "H" "E" "D" "A"

#$rpart$dat3
#[1] "B" "H"
```

For each model I want to select only those variables in `dat_list`, that are contained in the respective object of `model_list`. In this example, of course, the result is the same for each model.

I am able to do this using a nested `for` loop like below

```
subset_list <- list()

for (i in names(model_list)) {
  subset_list[[i]] <- list()
  for (j in names(dat_list)) {
    subset_list[[i]][[j]] <- dat[, model_list[[i]][[j]]]
  }
}

subset_list[1]
#$rpart
#$rpart$dat1
#     C     H     D     E     A    G
#1 0.49  0.78 -0.31 -0.62 -0.63 0.82
#2 0.74  0.07  1.51 -2.21  0.18 0.59
#3 0.58 -1.99  0.39  1.12 -0.84 0.92

#$rpart$dat2
#     H     E     D     A
#1  0.78 -0.62 -0.31 -0.63
#2  0.07 -2.21  1.51  0.18
#3 -1.99  1.12  0.39 -0.84

#$rpart$dat3
#     B     H
#1  1.60  0.78
#2  0.33  0.07
#3 -0.82 -1.99
```

This piece of code should be part of a function that iterates over some more models, selects important variables and re-estimates the models again. Since the data sets I am working on contain several hundred variables, I was wondering if anyone could suggest a more efficient / smarter way to accomplish this task. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you clarify, you want the column list in `model_list` to match its corresponding column list in `dat_list`? Based on index I presume?

Comment: Looking at the solution of @csgroen, I realize `dat_list` is not even necessary. But yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe one `lapply` should be more efficient then nested loops.

```
subset_list <- lapply(model_list, function (model) {
    dat1 <- dat[,model$dat1]
    dat2 <- dat[,model$dat2]
    dat3 <- dat[,model$dat3]
    list(dat1 = dat1, dat2 = dat2, dat3 = dat3)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed a much smarter solution. I guess I was focusing too hard on the loop.